# Error when running Excel Add-In Macro from Excel Ribbon

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I updated the code in an excel add-in I created that is saved on my company's shared drive.  I've added some of the add-ins macros under a custom tab on the Excel ribbon.  Before updating the code, I already had it set as an Active Application Add-In, so I figured I could just update the code and the buttons would work just like they were before.  However, when I click one of the custom ribbon buttons I get the error "Cannot run the macro "macro file path".  The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled".

I've googled for solutions already and most involve changing Trust Center Settings-->Macro Settings to Enable all macros and checking the Trust Access to the VBA project object model button, which I had done before updating the add-in code.

I've also opened up the VBE and see the add-in file in the Project Explorer window right next to the workbook I'm trying to run the add-in macro from.  Does anyone know why this is happening?  It was working fine until I updated the add-in code.

Here is the original add-in code:

```
Function BuildBudgetSQL(PageFilters As Range, Table As Range)
Application.Volatile
    'PageFilters As String, Year As Date, x_axis As String, y_axis As String)

    Dim cell As Range

    'Starts SQL statement
    BuildBudgetSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & "[" & Table.Offset(0, 2).Value & "]" & " WHERE "

    'Adds WHERE and AND clauses to SQL statement
    For Each cell In PageFilters
        BuildBudgetSQL = BuildBudgetSQL & "[" & cell.Value & "] " & cell.Offset(0, 1) & " '" & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value & "'" & " " & cell.Offset(1, -1).Value & " "
    Next

    'Chops off trailing " AND" and add ";" on end of SQL statement
    BuildBudgetSQL = Mid(BuildBudgetSQL, 1, Len(BuildBudgetSQL) - 2) & ";"

End Function

Sub GetBudgetTable()

Dim dbFilePath As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim cell As Range
Dim Year As String
Dim SQL As String

'For Each cell In Range("A1:A100")
    'If InStr(1, cell.Name, "SQL", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

        Year = Sheets("Report").Range("Year").Value
        SQL = Sheets("Report").Range("BudgetSQL").Value

        dbFilePath = "H:\CORP\CFR-2011_to_Current\Budget\2015\Budget Variance\Budget Variance - Pivot\Test\More Tests\Administrative\Database\" & Year & " Budget.accdb"
        Set db = Access.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(dbFilePath, False, True)
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

        Sheets("Budget Table").Range("a2:y50000").ClearContents
        Sheets("Budget Table").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        db.Close

        Sheets("Report").PivotTables("BudgetDetail").RefreshTable

    'End If
'Next
End Sub
```

And here's the new code:

```
Function BuildSQL(FieldNames As Range, Table As Range, PageFilters As Range)

Application.Volatile

Dim cell As Range

'Starts SQL statement
BuildSQL = "SELECT "

'Adds field names to SELECT clause of SQL statement
For Each cell In FieldNames
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        BuildSQL = BuildSQL & "[" & Table.Offset(0, 2).Value & "]." & "[" & cell.Value & "]" & ", "
    End If
Next

'Chops off trailing "," on end of SQL statement
BuildSQL = Mid(BuildSQL, 1, Len(BuildSQL) - 2)

'Adds FROM clause, table name, and WHERE clause
BuildSQL = BuildSQL & " FROM " & "[" & Table.Offset(0, 2).Value & "]" & " WHERE "

'Adds criteria to SQL statement's WHERE clause
For Each cell In PageFilters
    If cell.Value <> "" Then
        BuildSQL = BuildSQL & "[" & cell.Value & "] " & cell.Offset(0, 1) & " '" & cell.Offset(0, 2).Value & "'" & " " & cell.Offset(1, -1).Value & " "
    End If
Next

'Chops off trailing " AND" and add ";" on end of SQL statement
BuildSQL = Mid(BuildSQL, 1, Len(BuildSQL) - 2) & ";"

End Function

Sub GetBudgetTable()

Dim dbFilePath As String
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim cell As Range
Dim Year As String
Dim SQL As String

        Year = Sheets("Report").Range("Year").Value
        SQL = Sheets("Report").Range("BudgetSQL").Value

        'pulls budget
        dbFilePath = "H:\CORP\CFR-2011_to_Current\Budget\2015\Budget Variance\Budget Variance - Pivot\Test\More Tests\Administrative\Database\" & Year & " Budget.accdb"
        Set db = Access.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(dbFilePath, False, True)
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

        Sheets("Budget Table").Range("A2:AJ80000").ClearContents
        Sheets("Budget Table").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs
        db.Close

        'pulls actuals
        dbFilePath = "H:\CORP\CFR-2011_to_Current\Budget\2015\Budget Variance\Budget Variance - Pivot\Test\More Tests\Administrative\Database\" & Year & " Actuals - Summary.accdb"
        Set db = Access.DBEngine.OpenDatabase(dbFilePath, False, True)
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)

        Sheets("Budget Table").Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).CopyFromRecordset rs
        db.Close

        Sheets("Report").PivotTables("Pivot").RefreshTable

End Sub

Sub ActualDrilldown()
'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804259/vba-code-to-return-pivot-table-cells-row-column-and-page-fields-and-items/34830798?noredirect=1#comment57563829_34830798

Dim pvtCell As Excel.PivotCell
Dim pvtTable As Excel.PivotTable
Dim pvtField As Excel.PivotField
Dim pvtItem As Excel.PivotItem
Dim pvtParentItem As Excel.PivotField
Dim i As Long
Dim SQL As String
Dim dict As Scripting.Dictionary

Set dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

dict.Add "Jan", "Jan"
dict.Add "Feb", "Feb"
dict.Add "Mar", "Mar"
dict.Add "Apr", "Apr"
dict.Add "May", "May"
dict.Add "Jun", "Jun"
dict.Add "Jul", "Jul"
dict.Add "Aug", "Aug"
dict.Add "Sep", "Sep"
dict.Add "Oct", "Oct"
dict.Add "Nov", "Nov"
dict.Add "Dec", "Dec"

On Error Resume Next
Set pvtCell = ActiveCell.PivotCell
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "The cursor needs to be in a pivot table"
    Exit Sub
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If pvtCell.PivotCellType <> xlPivotCellValue Then
    MsgBox "The cursor needs to be in a Value field cell"
    Exit Sub
End If

SQL = "SELECT * FROM [Actual Detail] WHERE "

'Checks if PivotField.SourceName contains a month.  If not, exit sub; otherwise, adds Value Field Source to SQL statement
If dict.Exists(Left(pvtCell.PivotField.SourceName, 3)) = False Then
    MsgBox "A month field must be in the column field of the active pivot cell before drilling.", vbOKOnly
    Exit Sub
End If
SQL = SQL & "[" & Left(pvtCell.PivotField.SourceName, 3) & "]" & "IS NOT NULL AND "

'Adds rowfields and rowitems to SQL statement
For i = 1 To pvtCell.RowItems.Count
    Set pvtParentItem = pvtCell.RowItems(i).Parent
    SQL = SQL & "[" & pvtParentItem.Name & "]" & "=" & "'" & pvtCell.RowItems(i).Name & "'" & " AND "
Next i

'Adds columnfields and columnitems to SQL statement
For i = 1 To pvtCell.ColumnItems.Count
    Set pvtParentItem = pvtCell.ColumnItems(i).Parent
    SQL = SQL & "[" & pvtParentItem.Name & "]" & "=" & "'" & pvtCell.ColumnItems(i).Name & "'" & " AND "
Next i

'Chops off trailing "AND" on end of SQL statement
SQL = Mid(SQL, 1, Len(SQL) - 5) & ";"

Debug.Print SQL

End Sub
```

I know the code is long and isn't pretty, but if you want the full information, there it is.

I appreciate and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!  There were two things I needed to do:

1) I added ActiveWorkbook to the subs code where applicable.

2) This was the tricky part - I realized I have to remove the sub from the Excel ribbon and then add it back.  Apparently, when you update a sub in the add-in, the button on the Excel ribbon that runs that sub does not update.  You have to remove the button from the Excel ribbon and add it back on.

After doing both of these steps, the add-in worked correctly.

I sure hope there is a way around having to manually remove and add the add-in sub back each time I make a change to the add-in.  I'll google this and maybe open up a new question thread.